# ios 6 app compatible with previous versions

Tags: iphone, ios6

I want to make an application in iOS 6. At the same time I want this application is supported by iOS 5 and 4. Can anyone explain in detail How I cane make an app in iOS 6 compatible with previous versions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in xcode, in your app's project settings: set the deployment version to ios4 while setting the base sdk to ios 6

that's all there is as long as you dont use ios6 features but only code available on ios4 too

---

IF you want to conditionally use code check if the class you're using is available. - e.g.

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"MKMapKit")) { 
   // on ios6 
} else { 
   //dont have mapkit 
}
```

**dont check for specific os versions, check for features**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be targetting iOS 4. iOS 4 will restrict storyboard, ARC and lots of things. use iOS 5 as deployment version and iOS 6 sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you develop with the latest SDK available, and set your Deployment target in your project to be the minimum version you want to support.

However, because of the removed support for armv6 devices in the latest version of Xcode it will be difficult to support anything below at least the minimum for an iPhone4, and even then - many of those will have upgraded to a more modern OS.

As for writing code that supports this - Don't bother with the older `NSStringFromClass` function, use weak linking:

```
if ([MKMapKit class]) {
    // MKMapKit is available in this OS
} else {
    // MKMapKit is not available in this OS
}
```

This, and other ways of writing code that uses multiple iOS versions is described more fully in the [SDK Compatibility Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6) available from the Apple Developer Site.

Comment: Why is this not working but when I test it with the NSStringFromClass it does ?